# Invalid charset on $_POST

Tags: character-encoding

I'm with a problem about the charset of the $_POST. When I submited a form, case the string inserted on the InputText haved a special character or a accent, the value of this input on the $_POST array is corrupted with invalid characters.

Exemple:
I inserted on the input: "pão"
The $_POST show me: Array ( [input] => pÃ£o)

I'm using the CodeIgniter Framework with ISO-8859-1 charset. To improve my test, I used a mb_detect_encoding() and this function returned utf-8. :\

Below the code of important parts:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Default Character Set
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This determines which character set is used by default in various methods
| that require a character set to be provided.
|
*/
$config['charset'] = "iso-8859-1";

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Default Language
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This determines which set of language files should be used. Make sure
| there is an available translation if you intend to use something other
| than english.
|
*/
$config['language'] = "portugues";

$db['default']['char_set'] = "latin1";
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = "latin1_swedish_ci"; 

Form that was submited:
<form action="HTTP://localhost/portalsibe/index.php/grupos/cadastro" id="form" accept-charset="utf8" method="POST" name="frmPadrao" target="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: http://kunststube.net/frontback

Answer (score 2):

Try this solution, insert this jquery function in your script:

[Font](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/serialize-problem-with-latin-1-iso-8859-1-and-solution)

Credits:
Javier Poo, WeLinux S.A.
Oficina: 02-372.97.70, Celular:84039925
Bombero Ossa # 1010, Santiago
www.welinux.cl

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
param: function( a ) { 
    var s = []; 

    // If an array was passed in, assume that it is an array 
    // of form elements 
    if ( a.constructor == Array || a.jquery ){
        // Serialize the form elements 
        jQuery.each( a, function(){ 
            s.push(unescape(encodeURIComponent(escape(this.name))) + "=" + unescape(encodeURIComponent(escape(this.value)))); 
        }); 
    } 
    // Otherwise, assume that it's an object of key/value pairs 
    else{ 
        // Serialize the key/values 
        for ( var j in a ) 
            // If the value is an array then the key names need to be repeated 
            if ( a[j] && a[j].constructor == Array ) 
                jQuery.each( a[j], function(){ 
                    s.push(unescape(encodeURIComponent(escape(j)) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(escape(this)))); 
                }); 
            else 
                s.push(unescape(encodeURIComponent(escape(j)) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(escape(a[j])))); 
    } 
    // Return the resulting serialization 
    return s.join("&").replace(/ /g, "+"); 
},

serialize: function() { 
    return this.param(this.serializeArray()); 
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you change everything to utf8? Including database?

If yes, change all files, and set MySQL database (and tables) to `utf8_general_ci`. If you are using notepad++ to develop, go to `Encoding > Encode in UTF-8` (em português `Formatar > Codificação em UTF-8`).

Try not to use ISO-8859-1 as character encoding.

Comment: Thank you Rodrigo...

Unfortunately not, all of my project (files and db) is in ISO-8859-1/latin1. :(
Previously was normal... For example: If I used uft-8_decode($_POST) functions normally.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Then you need to "transform" all your files and database do ISO-8859-1. Don't forget to add in your PHP/HTML files, the encoding.

For example, in HTML4: `<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1">` and HTML5: `<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">`

Also, try to change teh enctype in your `<form>` tag to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and see if it works.